# BorderLayout - JPanel in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, border-layout

I want to create  two `JPanel` containers nested in another panel, but why does it show nothing as the code below? It seems that my two panels are not on the `ABC` panel?

```
public class ABC extends JPanel
{ 

      Frame frame;
      public  ABC(Frame frame)
       {
           super();
           this.frame = frame;
           setLayout(new BorderLayout());
           JPanel one = new JPanel();
           JPanel two = new JPanel();
           add(one,BorderLayout.NORTH);
           add(two,BorderLayout.CENTER);
           one.setVisible( true );
           two.setVisible( true );
       }
       public class one extends JPanel {
                  public one() {
                      setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                      createA();
                      setVisible(true);
                  }
              }
       public class two extends JPanel {
                   public two() {   
                       setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
                       createB();
                       setVisible(true);
                   }
               }
     private void createA(){
                add(ButtonA);
                add(ButtonAA);
                add(ButtonAAA);
               }
     private void createB(){
                   add(ButtonB);
               }
}
```

Comment: `JPanel two = new JPanel();`. It's just an empty panel, it won't show anything. Change it's background color, or add some components to it.

Comment: In `JPanel one = new JPanel` you are not creating instances of your new JPanels. You must actually call the constructors of `one` and `two`

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Don't mix Swing and AWT components without good reason. In this case, there is no good reason. Change `Frame frame;` to `JFrame frame;` and tweak other bits of code as warned by the compiler. 4) In this case, there is no good reason to extend `JPanel`. ..

Comment: .. 5) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Answer (score 0):

Ur using it in the wrong way, u must use youre own clases (one, two) not the JPANEL:

```
JPanel one = new one();
JPanel two = new two();
add(one,BorderLayout.NORTH);
add(two,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Btw, try to change the name of your clases can be confusing, to One, Two

Answer (score 0):

try to change the prefererSize of the panel one because when you put a panel in NORTH OR anywhere else but the CENTRE it should have a size 
use border to see the edge of the panel

```
one.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
two.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
one.setpreferredsize(new new dimension(width,height));
add(one,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```